# Pass parsed ng-repeat data into function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I'm using a ng-repeat to go over some json data to produce an unordered list. I have a ng-click handler on each list item, which when clicked I need to gather all the data from the current list item clicked (including the item.things (array)) and send it over to a below referenced 'delete' function.

I thought passing $event would do it but I can't seem to find the data in it.

Example:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="delete($event)">
   {{item.id}}
   <span ng-repeat="thing in item.things">
     {{thing.id}}
   </span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Which produces:

```
Item 1
  Thing X
  Thing Y
Item 2 
  Thing X
  Thing Y
```

..etc etc

Comment: Why not just do `ng-click="delete(item)"`?

Comment: @NewDev Wow, is it that easy?

Comment: I would think that discovering the local variable `$event` was harder

Comment: @NewDev HA, wow talk about thinking way to much into the problem, thanks for the information!

Comment: yea, that's why angular is so nice :) You can just grab it on the other side inside your controller then. item.id..pretty slick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="delete(item)">
```

This should work.